# Convertemptystringtonull not working in gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I'm trying to convert an empty string to null when editing a table in my gridview. I've tried several iterations and methods with no success. I'm suspecting that the issues is in my `ObjectDataSource` but don't know the correct syntax I need.

```
<asp:GridView 
    ID="grdMyDistributors"
    DataSourceID = "srcGetMyDistributors" 
    CssClass="GridViewStyle"
    DataKeyNames = "ID_Distributor"
    AutoGenerateColumns = "false" AutoGenerateEditButton = "true"
    GridLines="None"
    runat="server" >
    <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField
        DataField="DistributorName"
        HeaderText="Distributor" 
        convertemptystringtonull="true"
        ReadOnly = "True" />
    <asp:BoundField
        DataField="Distributor_Email_1"
        HeaderText="Distributor Email 1"
        convertemptystringtonull="true" >
        <ItemStyle BackColor="#f6f17c"/>
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField
        DataField="Distributor_Email_2"
        HeaderText="Distributor Email 2"
        convertemptystringtonull="true" >
        <ItemStyle BackColor="#f6f17c"/>
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField
        DataField="Minimum_Purchase_Amount"
        HeaderText="Minimum Purchase Amount"
        dataformatstring="{0:c}"
        convertemptystringtonull="true" >
        <ItemStyle BackColor="#f6f17c" />
    </asp:BoundField>
    </Columns> 
</asp:GridView>
```

Here is my `ObjectDataSource`:

```
    <asp:ObjectDataSource 
        ID="srcGetMyDistributors" 
        TypeName = "AAA.Distributors"
        SelectMethod = "GetDistributorsPagingFiltered"
        UpdateMethod = "UpdateDistributors"
        EnableCaching="false"
        ConvertNulltoDBNull = "true"
        runat="server" >
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ProfileParameter Name="ID_Account" PropertyName="ID_Account" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="grdMyDistributors" Name="ID_Distributor" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Here is my update method

```
    Public Shared Sub UpdateDistributors(ByVal ID_Distributor As Integer, ByVal Distributor_Email_1 As String, ByVal Distributor_Email_2 As String, ByVal Minimum_Purchase_Amount As Decimal)
        ' Initialize command
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(_connectionString)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("UpdateDistributors", con)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Connection = con

        ' Initialize parameters
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_Distributor", A2AID_Restaurant_To_Distributor)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Distributor_Email_1", Distributor_Email_1)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Distributor_Email_2", Distributor_Email_2)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Minimum_Purchase_Amount", Minimum_Purchase_Amount)

        ' Execute command
        Using (con)
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using

    End Sub
```

When I run the code as is, I get an error saying "Object of type 'System.DBNull' cannot be converted to type 'System.String'."  It's most likely erroring when it's trying to send to the Update method and expecting a string.  If I take out "ConvertNulltoDBNull = "true"  from the ObjectDataSource it complains that the SQL statement is expecting a value (meaning it's not sending the Null).  I've tried so many variations of this and can't find any info in the class library.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there something I could do in the class when I set the parameters?

Comment: I think it's coming from me setting the type in the procedure as a string "ByVal Distributor_Email_2 As String".  Therefore it's expecting a string and not a null.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: I found this resource but I'm still without an answer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366709.aspx

Answer (score 0):

use eval() for your gridview Columns

```
<%# Eval("DistributorName") == DBNull.Value ? "" : value.ToString()%>
```

> (its in C#)

```
 <asp:GridView 
ID="grdMyDistributors"
DataSourceID = "srcGetMyDistributors" 
CssClass="GridViewStyle"
DataKeyNames = "ID_Distributor"
AutoGenerateColumns = "false"
AutoGenerateEditButton = "true"
GridLines="None"
runat="server" >
 <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Seniority">
        <ItemTemplate>
           <%# Eval("DistributorName") == DBNull.Value ? "" :Eval("DistributorName").ToString()%>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Comment: sorry but could you explain this a little more.  I played around with the eval and couldn't get it to work

Comment: I appreciate the help, but unfortunately it did not work. The error does not occure when I'm displaying the data in the gridview, it occurs in edit mode after I try to post back an empty field.  So I tried your same method but with an edit template and I don't think my syntax is correct.             
<EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox
                    ID="Distributor_Email_2"
                    Text=<%# If(Bind("Distributor_Email_2") Is Nothing, DirectCast(Eval("Distributor_Email_2"), String), "")%>
                    runat=server />
            </EditItemTemplate>

Comment: I also tried setting the value to "DBnull" as a string (kind of like you're suggesting) and "NBNull" literally showed up in the database (it wasn't just blank)